# WCF RIA Services, The remote server returned an error: Not Found

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-security

This error occurs usually after some idle time when there was no server interaction. If I repeat the call, the server responds correctly and necessary data is returned. What might be the problem?

Additional details: web.config has the following line:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

And I access HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get current user name. Also, in Fiddler I saw the following message: "The requested resource requires user authentication".